# Customizing PS1 during automated server creation

Tags: bash

I'm [Automating Initial Server Setup with Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/automating-initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-18-04) on Digital Ocean using the user-data insert to start a new server.
I want to customize the `PS1` prompt in the `/etc/skel/.bashrc`
and I've moved it up to step one before it even creates the `sudo` user or copies `.bashrc` for that user.
Looking at `/etc/skel/.bashrc` it appears to have the changes on line 60
but when I `SSH` in as `jane_doe` her prompt is unchanged
I've considered adding a restart as the final step, but I'm not sure how that would help..
Since the file is being changed before she is created.
So, what should I be trying to do differently?

**initial_server_setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

########################
### SCRIPT VARIABLES ###
########################

# Name of the user to create and grant sudo privileges
USERNAME=jane_doe

# Whether to copy over the root user's `authorized_keys` file to the new sudo
# user.
COPY_AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FROM_ROOT=true

# Additional public keys to add to the new sudo user
# OTHER_PUBLIC_KEYS_TO_ADD=(
#     "ssh-rsa AAAAB..."
#     "ssh-rsa AAAAB..."
# )
OTHER_PUBLIC_KEYS_TO_ADD=(
"ssh-rsa AAAAB..."
)

####################
### SCRIPT LOGIC ###
####################

# customize TTY prompt
sed -i 's/\\\[\\033\[01;32m\\\]\\u@\\h\\\[\\033\[00m\\\]:\\\[\\033\[01;34m\\\]\\w\\\[\\033\[00m\\\]\\\$ /\\n\\@ \\\[\\e\[32;40m\\\]\\u\\\[\\e\[m\\\] \\\[\\e\[32;40m\\\]@\\\[\\e\[m\\\]\\n \\\[\\e\[32;40m\\\]\\H\\\[\\e\[m\\\] \\\[\\e\[36;40m\\\]\\w\\\[\\e\[m\\\] \\\[\\e\[33m\\\]\\\\\$\\\[\\e\[m\\\] /' /etc/skel/.bashrc
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '

# Add sudo user and grant privileges
useradd --create-home --shell "/bin/bash" --groups sudo "${USERNAME}"

# Check whether the root account has a real password set
encrypted_root_pw="$(grep root /etc/shadow | cut --delimiter=: --fields=2)"

if [ "${encrypted_root_pw}" != "*" ]; then
    # Transfer auto-generated root password to user if present
    # and lock the root account to password-based access
    echo "${USERNAME}:${encrypted_root_pw}" | chpasswd --encrypted
    passwd --lock root
else
    # Delete invalid password for user if using keys so that a new password
    # can be set without providing a previous value
    passwd --delete "${USERNAME}"
fi

# Expire the sudo user's password immediately to force a change
chage --lastday 0 "${USERNAME}"

# Create SSH directory for sudo user
home_directory="$(eval echo ~${USERNAME})"
mkdir --parents "${home_directory}/.ssh"

# Copy `authorized_keys` file from root if requested
if [ "${COPY_AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FROM_ROOT}" = true ]; then
    cp /root/.ssh/authorized_keys "${home_directory}/.ssh"
fi

# Add additional provided public keys
for pub_key in "${OTHER_PUBLIC_KEYS_TO_ADD[@]}"; do
    echo "${pub_key}" >> "${home_directory}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
done

# Adjust SSH configuration ownership and permissions
chmod 0700 "${home_directory}/.ssh"
chmod 0600 "${home_directory}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
chown --recursive "${USERNAME}":"${USERNAME}" "${home_directory}/.ssh"

# Disable root SSH login with password
sed --in-place 's/^PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
if sshd -t -q; then
    systemctl restart sshd
fi

# Add exception for SSH and then enable UFW firewall
ufw allow OpenSSH
ufw --force enable
```

**/etc/skel/.bashrc**

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\n\@ \[\e[32;40m\]\u\[\e[m\] \[\e[32;40m\]@\[\e[m\]\n \[\e[32;40m\]\H\[\e[m\] \[\e[36;40m\]\w\[\e[m\] \[\e[33m\]\\$\[\e[m\] '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

Comment: Have you considered just commenting the line out and adding your own definition instead?

Comment: I don't understand.. that is my definition
I've considered just adding a `.bashrc` file for jane_doe after her creation.. but I'd rather do it as the default for any new user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that when I got it to work manually I had uncommented a line to force color prompt = true

```
# customize TTY prompt
sed -i 's/#force_color_prompt=yes/ force_color_prompt=yes/' /etc/skel/.bashrc
```